# ASP.NET MVC Content folder - URLs changed in source for CSS/images but not for JS?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

If I have this in my Site.Master file:

```
<link href="../../Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

and then go to View Source on page of my site (when deployed to actual server), it renders like this:

```
<link href="Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

But if I have a JS file in the Scripts/ folder, it doesn't mimic the same behavior.  Where is the magic?  Is there some setting somewhere that is causing this?

Thanks,

~ Justin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I always use the Url helper to make sure.

```
<link href="<%= Url.Content( "~/content/site.css" ) %>"
      rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript"
        src="<%= Url.Content( "~/scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" ) %>">
</script>
```

In fact, I've actually replaced this all by HtmlHelper extensions that do the same thing.

```
<%= Html.Stylesheet( Url.Content( "~/content/site.css ) ) %>
<%= Html.Javascript( Url.Content( "~/scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" ) ) %>
```

Comment: Ah.  I didn't know about Url.Content.  That is useful.  But I'd still like to understand why one is rewritten in the page source and the other isn't.

Answer (score 2):

The head has the runat="server" option set which means that it performs this "magic" server-side for link references. AFAIK this does not happen for scripts references.

Comment: If that were true, since both things are in the HEAD, wouldn't both get rewritten?

Comment: You've thought. I haven't dug around enough in the mechanics of but I know for fact this works. Take out the runat="server" from the head and see what happens.

My guess is that Microsoft specifically looks for the link tag and not the script tag.

Comment: See also
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446533/what-is-the-status-of-runatserver-tags-in-asp-net-mvc for more info