# Will aspx not see changes made by javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am changing the contents of a span with javascript. I can see that it has changed with view source.

When I try to get the contents in a c# function right after, it still has the old value.

My guess is that asp is just seeing the html that it sent the client, and that javascript is changing the client html of which asp cannnot see?

this was my only guess on how to explain it. Would this be correct?

Thanks.

Comment: How are you doing this change? Show some code

Comment: also look into browser caching of html

Comment: The server side can't differentiate data entered by javascript or by a person, nor does it care. When you do a `POST` or `GET` the changes are reflected the same way.

Comment: Make sure to familiarize yourself with the ASP.NET Page Life Cycle (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx).  Getting data into the ViewState is essential (as many of the answers below point out).  However equally essential is knowing when that ViewState is loaded and accessible to the code-behind.  For example, any code you write in a page's Init() function will not be able to access the updated data, as Init() is called before the ViewState is loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your guess is correct!

Javascript sees only the client side and ASP.NET only the server side. If you make some change on the client side and you want to server side to be aware of that change, you can make use of **AJAX**.

See [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) for more info.

In .NET you can use a WebService, a Controller, or a Page for receiving the ajax call.

Answer (score 3):

Unless what you are changing support POSTing the values back to the server, then your changes will be discarded.   `<span>`'s do not get POSTed to the server.

If you change the value of INPUT's however, then the server will be able to see those new values on the nest page submission POST, provided they are `runat=server`.

Answer (score 2):

ASPX is **SERVER SIDE**.  Javascript is **CLIENT SIDE**.  The two do not mix unless you make a call back to a webservice, or something similar.

Your `<span>` change is only on the client, and the server is not aware of it.  Look into AJAX as a solution if you wish to communicate interaction back to the server.

Answer (score 1):

add `runat="server"` to your span. this will cause it to get picked up by viewstate and the new value will be available during postbacks.

edit: according to jrummel and testing by mikemanne, a span will not post back even when decorated with `runat=server`.

I would suggest using an input (as others suggest) instead of a span if you want the value consistently available on the server.

Comment: No, changing the span's value with javascript will not update ViewState, nor will a span's value POST.

Comment: @jrummell any type of element can be tagged as runat server and it will be included in viewstate during a postback, including spans.

Comment: If you recalculate the ViewState hash with javascript, sure, I suppose you could. Do you have any resources to back that up?

Comment: @jrummell i'm not able to find actual documentation on it, i know it from experience. here is a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446533/what-is-the-status-of-runat-server-tags-in-asp-net-mvc it is recieved by the server as an HTMLGenericControl, and you need to give it an ID to be able to easily access it.

Comment: My understanding is: as long as the span is flagged as a sever control (runat=server), its contents will be updated and accessible in the code-behind when the form is posted-back.  Logically, this is no different than using JS to set the text in an input field.  In neither case must you do anything to the hidden VIEWSTATE field.  (In fact, I suspect any attempt to modify the VIEWSTATE field on the client side will result in a thrown exception at postback time.)

Comment: The OP is asking about how to see changes to a span made by javascript in codebehind. Span elements don't POST to the server, even if they are declared `runat=server`. So without ajax, or copying the value to a POST-able element (input for example), you will not see the changed value in code behind.

Comment: Just did a quick test, and @jrummell is correct: even when marked with runat=server, a SPAN's innerHTML will not be pushed to the code-behind during a postback.  I guess that's why, in the past, I've tended to use HIDDEN fields when I wanted to push JS-modified data back to the code-behind, since INPUTs of all types are included during a postback.  Thanks for bringing us along, jrummell!  :)