# declared variable is not accessible in part of view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

There is one strange thing. I declared some variable on start of view, but in  tags it wasn't accessible. I could declare variable with same name between  tags. Out of the  tags, original variable has been accessible again.

Maybe, reason can be that there is runatserver.
Code looks like this:

```
<% var variable = something; %>
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<%!-- <% variable = something else; %> --%> // impossible variable don't exist in this context
<% var variable = something else %> // so this row instead of last one 
...
</head>
<% if (variable == something) 
       ThisFunctionWillBeExecute();
   if (variable == somethigelse)
       ThisFunctionWillNotBeExecuted();
%>
```

I don't understand why and i can't google some explanation. Do you understand it? Some links? How it can works, are parts of code processed separately?

Don't me ask why there is use this strange solution, i'm not author of the code, i just made some changes in it.

EDITED: I forgot write that it is masterpage.

Comment: And how does behave without `runat="server"`?

Comment: Without runatserver it works normal. It is not able declare it again and it is accessible in all code. But i don't need this solve, I'm just interst why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ASP.NET MVC context if you use a `runat="server"` tag on ANY element, such as a DIV it will render that code as a separate **method** in the compiled page. So any existing variables go out of context, while variables declared in that tag goes out-of-context after the `runat="server"` tag.

Source:
[What is the status of runat="server" tags in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446533/what-is-the-status-of-runat-server-tags-in-asp-net-mvc)